# Desk Reference Question: Linear Algebra and its Applications by Lay or Strang? Or Handbook of Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, soft-question

I would like a good working desk reference for linear algebra for someone in applied mathematics (no proving abstract theorems). I saw the Handbook of Linear Algebra as well, but I am concerned it may be too theoretical.

I am partial to Strang's text, as it appears more comprehensive and rigorous than Lay's but the subjects still seem very applied as opposed to theoretical. However, I wanted to know which one is most appropriate for a Master's level applied mathematician?

Comment: What do you mean by abstract theorems? What is an example of applied theorem? At master's level in mathematics you shouldn't really shun linear algebra proofs, no matter how applied you are (you do need to have something to apply, after all)...

Comment: If you're an applied mathematician, why not stick to Strang?  I myself find Horn and Johnson to be fairly comprehensive, but it does little (if anything) to cover the "basics".

Comment: @A.P. I know its somewhat subjective, but theorems about how to get results, or bound results, are rather "applied" whereas theorems that say things like "there exists a solution..." or results that are primarily useful for proving theorems, not calculating results. Much like Skorokhod's representation theorem in probability theory.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I do really like Strang, but I am concerned that I am missing out on a more comprehensive text that still stays within the bounds of what a non-research mathematician would use on a regular basis.

Comment: @Bey I think that any Linear Algebra text strays a bit beyond "masters level mathematics", whatever that entails.  Another reference I like a lot is Bhatia's Matrix Analysis, which is daunting if you want to use it as a textbook but *exceedingly useful* if you want to skim through the table of contents for the relevant bound result (if you're not too worried about the proof).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thx. Ill take a look at that. Is there anything you find deficient about Strang?

Comment: @Bey nothing deficient, but it's ultimately limited by the fact that it assumes you have no foundation in linear algebra.  Presumably you have a solid foundation at this point, so a lot of the textbook not particularly helpful to you.  If you want something comprehensive about useful (potentially "recent" results), Bhatia is as close as you can get within the realm of "proper textbooks".

Comment: @Bey also: I meant any non-undergraduate linear algebra text strays a bit beyond the "masters level" at some point.  You never know what kinds of results are going to be useful, though, if you plan on doing some amount of research.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks again. Very helpful points. I'll keep this in mind. Have you ever used the Handbook of Linear Algebra?

Comment: @Bey You're welcome! I have not.

Comment: @Bey I just found it online and downloaded it, actually.  It seems extremely useful.  I does assume, however, that you "know what you're looking for", and is definitely not what I would consider a textbook.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yea, way too long for that, but its got a great index. I think I'll consider it since it's a little better organized than Strang, which is more pedagogical in focus (obviously, since it s aproper textbook). Thanks for following up and giving me your assessment!

Comment: @Bey thanks for the tip, I'll probably end up using the Handbook!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ordering Handbook of Linear Algebra, 2nd Ed by Hogben. Large tome, but great index and binding.